# Unexpected String output

Tags: java

I have programmed following class in Java

```
public class Factorial
    {
        final String[] promotion: {"watch", "on", "youtube:", "Mickey en de stomende drol", (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ)"};
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        System.out.println(shoutPromotion(promotion));
    }

    public static String shoutPromotion(String[] promotion)
    {   String result = "";
        for(int i = 1; i < promotion.length; i++)
            result += promotion[i] + " ";
        return result;
    }
}
```

But when I run the program I see following output in the console:

on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ)

The word watch disappeeard. How does this come?

Comment: `i = 1` <-- look at this more closely;

Comment: arrays start with the index `0` and not `1`, and since you  start your loop at `i=1` you skip the first element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array index starts with 0 not 1.

This

```
for(int i = 1; i < promotion.length; i++)
```

Change it to

```
for(int i = 0; i < promotion.length; i++)
```